# The best approach to adding images in an article in Django

Tags: django

It's a quite typical task to add several images with captions in arbitrary position within an article; what's the best way to do so in Django?

Let's assume I have two models:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    heading = models.CharField(max_length=350)
    text = models.TextField()

class ImageModel(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField( upload_to = 'static/images/', max_length=300)
    img_alt = models.CharField(max_length=550, blank = True)
```

Now, I'd like to add a couple of images with captions in an article. Its text is stored with HTML formatting:

```
<p>Paragraph 1</p>

[Image 1 + caption]

<p>Paragraph 2</p>

[Image 2 + caption]

<p>Paragraph 3.</p>

<...>
```

What should I do to accomplish this? I guess it's necessary to create a custom tag, and make a tool for inserting this tag in a TextField with help of JS. While inserting, the id of a selected instance of ImageModel has to be passed somehow into the tag. And finally, this custom tag should be processed when rendering a template. Am I right? Is there any easier and more straightforward approach?

(I use Django 2.0.)

Answer (score 1):

that would be better to use an **WYSIWYG Editor** for articles, this way you will have better text formatting too. [Django-ckeditor](https://github.com/django-ckeditor/django-ckeditor) is one of that give you a model field named `RichTextUploadingField`, also you can find more [here](https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/wysiwyg/).